# Using out parameters and getting pass by reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC application that sends mock text messages, and in it I have two models: Contacts and Textmessages.

When the user creates a Textmessage, the view requires that they enter a phone number and their message. When submitted, the controller verifies if the phone number (contact) exists in the database before allowing the message to be created.

If the contact exists, the confirmation screen needs to display the message details (phone number and message) as well as the name of the recipient.

I'm using out parameters to send back the name info as strings, but I am getting an error:

> Cannot call action method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(SMSText.Models.Textmessage, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)' on controller 'SMSText.Controllers.TextmessagesController' because the parameter 'System.String& firstName' is passed by reference.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create( [Bind(Include = 
        "ID,Message,EnteredPrefix,EnteredPhoneNumber")] Textmessage textmessage, 
        out string firstName, out string surName )
    {
        firstName = "";
        surName = "";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool exists = db.Contacts.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(contact => contact.AreaCode == textmessage.EnteredPrefix && contact.PhoneNumber == textmessage.EnteredPhoneNumber)
                .Count() >0;

            if (exists)
            {
                var contactObj = db.Contacts.First(contact => contact.AreaCode == textmessage.EnteredPrefix && contact.PhoneNumber == textmessage.EnteredPhoneNumber)
                firstName = contactObj.Forename;
                surName = contactObj.Surname;
                db.Textmessages.Add(textmessage);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Details", textmessage );
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Error", textmessage);
            }
        }
        return View(textmessage);
    }
```

If I understand the error message, the name info is being passed as a reference rather than as an actual string, but I do not know how to fix this.

How can I get past this error? Is there a better method to accomplish what I am doing?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need the `firstName` and `surName` as `out` parameters?

Comment: why not just return an object instead? also with out params, you have to define it above your method, as a property (ie - `public string firstName, lastName;    public ActionResult.....(out firstName, out lastName, ......`)

Comment: This won't work. An Action method is called by the MVC API and it does not support `out` because there is no way it could do something with the resulting values.  _"to send back"_  - to where ?

Comment: You are correct Henk. I didnt think that was possible too so, suggested using a ViewData/ViewBag/TempData to accomplish this. See my answer below using ViewData as one possible way to achieve this. OP seems to be using the TextMessage model that he is returning. So, the best way would be to use some kind of Controller-View communication mechanism via ViewBag/ViewData/TempData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are unnecessarily over-killing the call by trying to use out parameters. Why dont you simple use the ViewData once you find the matching contact and then use in the view?

```
var contact  = db.Contacts.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(contact => contact.AreaCode == textmessage.EnteredPrefix && contact.PhoneNumber == textmessage.EnteredPhoneNumber);

if(contact != null && contact.Any())
{
   ViewData["Contact"] = contact.FirstOrDefault();
   db.Textmessages.Add(textmessage);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Details", textmessage );
}


and then in the view you can read it back:

@{
    var contact = (Contact)ViewData["Contact"];
}
```

Please let me know how did it work for you...

Comment: Thanks @Manish, I am trying to implement your suggestion now. 
May I ask you this: Is the contact passed back an object? or, how do I access the first and surnames in the view? 
(again, sorry for such basic questions!)

Comment: When I insert your suggested code in the view, I get an intellisense warning: "The type or namespace name 'Contact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Is there something I need to add to tell it to look at the Contact model?

Comment: Yes, that should be your Contacts model. I missed the 's' that might be causing confusion. Sorry for that. But the idea is that you can find the contact, load you Contacts model with that and pass that to your view using ViewData (or ViewBag if you dont want to type cast in the view). Once you do, you will have the object in the View and you should be able to access the properties of your Contacts model eg FirstName, LastName etc. Also, I was missing the = sign after var contact. If that is where you were stucj it should help you. try using the updated code. Let me know how did it go.

Comment: Okay, I see you now that you are getting error trying to resolve your Contact(s) model in the view. You can try prefixing the namespace of the Contact(s) model class (eg var contact = (MyWebProj.Models.Contact)ViewData["Contact"];) 
or you can try putting using statement on the top:

@using MyWebProj.Models